# Is forcing a constructor signature a valid reason to use an abstract class rather than an interface?

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class

For a project, I have written the following interface:

```
public interface IManipulation {
    void applyManipulation (double value);
}
```

Since I would like to force all implementing classes to use a certain constructor signature, I have been considering to change the interface into something like the following abstract class:

(**edit**: I forgot that it's not possible to have an abstract constructor, so I changed the "solution" below a bit)

```
public abstract class Manipulation {
    private Signal signal;

    public Manipulation (Signal signal) {
        this.signal = signal;
    }

    public abstract void applyManipulation (double value);

    protected Signal getSignal () {
        return signal;
    }
}
```

The reason for wanting to force this constructor is because every implentation should have an instance of Signal available. (and it should not be possible to reassign this signal)

Is this a valid reason to replace the interface with an abstract class (and live with the limitations that come with it), or are there any other potential solutions?

Comment: Have you tried compiling that code? It doesn't compile. So the question is moot. There is no such thing as an abstract constructor in Java. You can't force a class to have a specific constructor.

Comment: Oops, my bad... Give me a moment to fix the question.

Comment: If you want to enforce a certain signature to instantiate an object of your class you should declare an factory method and make all constructors private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of an abstract class you should use an init method for that purpose.

```
public interface MyInterface{
    public void init(YourParam p);
    //... other methods
}
```

in the init you check, if the class is allready initialised if yes, just return.

So you have still an interface and can extend from other classes.
Instead of the constructor you will call the init method for your initialization

**EDIT:**

```
public interface IManipulation {
    void init(Signal s);
    void applyManipulation (double value);
}
```

You should use abstract classes only, if you have implementation details in it, which are shared by all subclasses. For Method signatures use interfaces

Answer (score 0):

You can make empty constructor private in the abstract class:

```
abstract class AbstractManipulation {
    private final Integer signal;

    private AbstractManipulation() {

        signal = null;
    }

    public AbstractManipulation (Integer signal) {
        this.signal = signal;
    }
}


class Manipulation extends AbstractManipulation {

    public Manipulation(Integer signal) {
        super(signal);
    }

    // Cannot redeclare
    //public Manipulation() {
    //}
}
```

Then:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    // Will not work
    //Manipulation m = new Manipulation();

    // This one will
    Manipulation m = new Manipulation(1);
}
```

Comment: this will not "enforce" the constructor signature as i can add a subclass with a constructor like this:

    public CrazyManipulation(Object crazyParam) {
        super(0);
    }

Comment: @bloodmagew You still have to pass the signal.

Answer (score 0):

You should not choose for technical reasons but rather logical, ie an abstract class is used when you have a realtion with the sub-classes like for example person: student, teacher. An interface is used when you want to impose a service contract for classes that may not have a relationship between them.